# How can I make websites that use non-latin UTF-8 fonts viewable in iOS

Tags: ios, fonts, mobile-safari

Whenever I open webpages (created by other people) that contain custom fonts (non-latin), all I see is square boxes.  This is of course because the required fonts are

1. Not one of the many fonts that come with iOS
2. The person who created the website did not embed the custom font in the webpage so the site can be viewable in iOS

So I am trying to create an App that allows me to somehow tell UIWebView to use my custom font if the webpage contains certain unicode characters. Of course, I will have to include the custom font in the app resources directory.

Comment: Also, don't forget all the issues that come with UIWebView (No built in caching support, horrid javascript implementation, no support for location in HTML 5, etc.)